# How do I correct for endianness in the Well-Known Binary format?

Tags: c, parsing, geospatial, endianness

I'm trying to figure out the [WKB Format](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/well-known-binary-wkb-format/) and am getting caught up with the endianness.

Taking that example, here's a Point geometry represented in hex:

```
000000000140000000000000004010000000000000
```

split into bytes: `[name of part:number of bytes]`

```
[endiannes:1][type:4][x:8][y:8]
```

The question is, if I was trying to switch the endianness, would I:

- Read the first byte, reverse all the consecutive bytes, then split it into individual parts?

Or

- Split into individual parts, read endianness, reverse bytes in individual parts?

Comment: I second Jon's answer - the byte-ordering is most sensibly done per element. NOTE: Java does not have any unsigned types: if you have a data type with '1-byte unsigned integers' you need a java `short` to store all possible values; likewise, you need a `long` to store all possible values of a 4-byte unsigned int. (obviously, 32 bits is 32 bits, so you can cram the bits of a uint32_t into a Java int, but when you try top print or operate on really large values (with the high bit set), it won't work as you expect because it will treat them as negative values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option. –  Jon

If you want to make a WKB with switched endianness, you also have to change the first byte from 00 to 01 or contrary, of course.